# Create a session scoped bean in spring security

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I need to create a POJO class that will store information pertaining to a user. In spring security, my authorities table has an extra column of instituionIds, it is a CSV string that will be needed in various DAO calls. I need to set the values of this class, which will be needed when querying the database.

```
@Component
@Scope("session")
public class InstitutionList {

    private String institutionList = "";

    public String getInstitutionList() {
        return institutionList;
    }

    public void setInstitutionList(String institutionList) {
        this.institutionList = institutionList;
    }
}
```

I need to use this in my custom UserDetailsService implementation

```
@Transactional
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserDetailsServiceImpl.class);
    private @Autowired ACSAdminUsersService acsAdminUsersService;
    private @Autowired ACSAdminAuthoritiesService acsAdminAuthoritiesService;
    private String[] authority;

    public ACSAdminUsers getUserByAdminUsername(String username) {
        logger.info("Getting user by username");
        ACSAdminUsers user = acsAdminUsersService.getUserByAdminUsername(username);
        if(user!=null) acsAdminUsersService.addLogInInfo(username);
        return user;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        ACSAdminUsers user = getUserByAdminUsername(username);
        logger.info("Username is : " + username);
        logger.info("user is : " + user);

        authority = acsAdminAuthoritiesService.getAuthoritiesForRole(user.getRole());
        logger.info("User role is : " + authority);
        if(authority == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User : "+username+" has no authorities." );
        }else {
        boolean accountNonExpired = true;
        boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
        boolean accountNonLocked = true;

        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(username,user.getAdmin_pass(),
                true,accountNonExpired,credentialsNonExpired,
                accountNonLocked,
                getAuthorities(username));
        }
    }

    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(String username) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authList = null;

        authList=new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

        for(int i = 0; i < authority.length; i++) {
            SimpleGrantedAuthority s = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(this.authority[i]);
            authList.add(s);
        }
        return authList;
    }
}
```

In the above java class I need to query the database and fetch, along with authorities, institutionIds which need to be used in queries throughout the application.

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own `InstitutionContextHolder` and use a threadlocal to store the object. In this way you can acces this object in every class you want. You can take a look at the SecurityContextHolder for examples.